# How can I calculate this integral? $ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^c \Phi(a x+b) \exp \left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right) d x$

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, integration

I know how to calculate this:
$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \Phi(a x+b) \exp \left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right) d x=\Phi\left(\frac{b}{\sqrt{1+a^2}}\right)$

but i am struggling with this:

$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^c \Phi(a x+b) \exp \left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right) d x=\Phi_2\left(\frac{b}{\sqrt{1+a^2}}, c ;-\frac{a}{\sqrt{1+a^2}}\right)$.

where $\Phi_2\left(\cdot, \cdot ;\rho \right)$ is the bivariate cummulative Gaussian distribution with correlation $\rho$.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What is the definition of $\Phi_2$?

Comment: This sort of looks like a *definition* of $\Phi_2.$

Comment: @Zhanxiong i have added the definition.

Comment: @whuber This was also my first thought, but i cant see it.

Comment: Use algebra to solve for $(a,b)$ in terms of $(b/\sqrt{1+a^2},-a/\sqrt{1+a^2}).$ There are two cases: $a\ge 0$ and $a\lt 0.$

Comment: @whuber thanks for the quick answer. But i dont know what u mean "with Use algebra to solve for $(a,b)$ in terms of $\left(b / \sqrt{1+a^2}, - a / \sqrt{1+a^2}\right)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I take it that $\Phi_2$ is the bivariate *standard* normal cdf with correlation $\rho$.  Then, letting $X$ and $Y$ denote iid standard normal random variables,
$$
\begin{align}
&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^c \Phi(a x+b) \exp \left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right) d x\\&=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^c \int_{-\infty}^{ax+b} \exp \left(-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}\right) dy\,d x
\\&=P(X\le c \cap Y\le aX+b)
\\&=P(X\le c \cap Y-aX\le b)
\\&=P(Z_1\le c\cap Z_2\le\frac{b}{\sqrt{1+a^2}})
\\&=\Phi_2(c,\frac{b}{\sqrt{1+a^2}}; \rho)
\end{align}
$$
where $Z_1=X$ and $Z_2=\frac{Y-aX}{\sqrt{1+a^2}}$ and $\rho=\operatorname{corr}(Z_1,Z_2)=-\frac a{\sqrt{1+a^2}}$.

Comment: Thank u for your calculation :)